# Verifying a SMIME-signature with Perl and OpenSSL

Tags: perl, openssl, smime

I try to make a Perl-Script that verifies a SMIME-message "manually".
I really tried a lot but it is not working.

Most of the time the verify puts 
"Signature longer than key" 
or just gives a false return.

If I do it with OpenSSL at the console it works like a charm.

```
CER=mycert
KEY=mykey
MSG=msg.txt
PLA=plain.txt

# create keys with:
# openssl req -x509 -nodes -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout mykey -out mycert

echo -n "test" > $PLA

# sign
openssl cms -sign -md sha1 -subject "test" -from "sam"  -to "alice" 
  -signer $CER -inkey $KEY -in $PLA -out $MSG

# verify
openssl smime -verify -purpose any -in $MSG -CAfile $CER 
  -CApath /etc/ssl/certs

>> Verification successful
```

That produces and verifies msg.txt

```
To: alice
From: sam
Subject: test
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/signed; protocol="application/pkcs7-signature";     
micalg="sha1"; boundary="----654C4F221B45801BF9249BC8B2EBC320"

This is an S/MIME signed message

------654C4F221B45801BF9249BC8B2EBC320
test
------654C4F221B45801BF9249BC8B2EBC320
Content-Type: application/pkcs7-signature; name="smime.p7s"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="smime.p7s"

MIIEZgYJKoZIhvcNAQcCoIIEVzCCBFMCAQExCTAHBgUrDgMCGjALBgkqhkiG9w0B
BwGgggJfMIICWzCCAcSgAwIBAgIJAJeRsnkW7iHCMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMEUx
```

*I shorten it here.*

```
Eep0LlT+ThDmdSWm8OIPA4f5UCI5+jWB91Nf5CqKFhuua2obZmAOqZXcX4E6VdLV
taorGZL0OCiGuUY94QJEdoJZ7rlpkwFBBVE=

------654C4F221B45801BF9249BC8B2EBC320--
```

Now I try to show it with very simple Perl. I simplified it in cut away the MIME-handling and just use the values inline from msg.txt.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Crypt::OpenSSL::X509;
use Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA;
use MIME::Base64;

my $in = "msg.txt";
my $crt = "mycert";

my $cert = Crypt::OpenSSL::X509->new_from_file ($crt);
my $pubkey = $cert->pubkey ();
my $rsa = Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA->new_public_key ($pubkey);

my $ct = "test";

my $sig = "MIIEZgYJKoZIhvcNAQcCoIIEVzCCBFMCAQExCTAHBgUrDgMCGjALBgkqhkiG9w0B
BwGgggJfMIICWzCCAcSgAwIBAgIJAJeRsnkW7iHCMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMEUx
```

*I skipped the rest. It is equivalent to the signature-string in msg.txt*

```
Eep0LlT+ThDmdSWm8OIPA4f5UCI5+jWB91Nf5CqKFhuua2obZmAOqZXcX4E6VdLV
taorGZL0OCiGuUY94QJEdoJZ7rlpkwFBBVE=";

$sig = decode_base64 ($sig);   # make it binary
if ($rsa->verify ($ct, $sig))
{
  print "\nverified!\n";
}

# verify fails with "Signature longer than key" or returns false.
```

I have no idea why it is not working. I would appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: I had some major misunderstanding. SMIME signes with pkcs7. So I need to extract the signature first. If so it works fine.
So the verify expects a signature and not the whole pkcs7-string.

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest you to go with openssl function PKCS7_verify() https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/demos/smime/smver.c#L63

You can take a look how to bind openssl functions directly to perl via FFI at my current project - https://github.com/0x62ash/crypt-openssl-cms/blob/master/lib/Crypt/OpenSSL/CMS.pm